# About limit of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $J=[0,1]$ and $x\in C[0,1]$, that is a continuous function on $[0,1]$.
Can I say that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\frac{1}{n^2}}^1\left\rvert \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}-x(t)\right\lvert\;dt =\int_0^1\left\lvert \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}-x(t)\right\rvert\;dt$$

> If yes, what is the theory? That of improper integrals? If no, why? Thanks!

Comment: That follows from monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: It is the definition of the improper integral in the rhs.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\frac{1}{n^2}}^1\left\rvert \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}-x(t)\right\lvert\;dt = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0+}\int_{\varepsilon}^1\left\rvert \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}-x(t)\right\lvert\;dt=\int_0^1\left\lvert \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}-x(t)\right\rvert\;dt$$

The second equality is the definition of the [improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral).

Comment: (+1) My comment 11 hours before was indeed incomplete (I forgot to mention your 1st equality). To the OP: note moreover that since the integrand is $>0,$ this limit exists and is either a positive real number or $+\infty.$ Actually it is finite but this answer holds without needing to prove it.